How to Take a Screenshot of a Full ListView in Flutter
I am working on a Flutter application where I need to capture a screenshot of a ListView that might have many items, possibly requiring scrolling. My goal is to take a screenshot of the entire list, not just the visible part on the screen.

Using the screenshot package to capture the visible part of the screen, but it only captures what's currently visible.
Wrapping the ListView in a RepaintBoundary, but again it only captures the visible portion.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ScreenshotExample(),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenshotExample extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Screenshot Example')),
      body: Screenshot(
        controller: screenshotController,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.camera),
        onPressed: () async {
          final image = await screenshotController.capture();
          // Handle the captured image
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot#capturing-a-list-widget
